# Getting basic-auth username in php

Tags: php

How can I access the apache basic-auth username in a PHP script?

Answer (score 19):

Simply access this variable:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
```

Answer (score 3):

Check what you have in $_SERVER (print_r($_SERVER)), sometimes $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] is not available.

If you have value for $_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"], you may use:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]) {
        $auth = $_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"];
        $auth_array = explode(" ", $auth);
        $un_pw = explode(":", base64_decode($auth_array[1]));
        $un = $un_pw[0];
        $pw = $un_pw[1];
    }
```

(copied from https://www.codepunker.com/blog/php-a-primer-on-the-basic-authorization-header)

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that the location [depends on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44849690/3316645) in use:

- `$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]` - CGI standard
- `$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]` - APACHE
- `$_SERVER["AUTH_USER"]` - IIS

Answer (score 1):

At my clients hoster `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]` were empty but `$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"]` was set!

```php
if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"] == "admin")
    echo "Welcome, admin!";
else
    echo "Access denied";
```